# how to fix a running proplem android

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-manifest

This problem is faced when I am copying another copy of a project that is similar by name and on the same disk but after a few seconds I noticed this and cancel the operation of copying the other project, unfortunately, it seems to override some of the files in the first project

Error message when Running the first project :

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

---

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\TrafficAccident\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild? Please try again before run your application

Comment: This isn't 'running', this is installing.

Comment: remove your project output folder and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest file add android:exported="true" in the launcher activity tag

```
       <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```